# Google Chrome UI in WinForms VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, winforms, google-chrome, user-interface

Is there a library that I can add to my app so I have the google chrome UI? I don't need the WebBrowser control called WebKit. I only need the WinForms UI so I can have the tabppages like in google chrome.

Comment: So u simply need tabs on your form?

Answer (score 0):

WinForms provides a [TabControl class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol(v=vs.110).aspx) which may be sufficient for your needs.

See also [Winforms: Browser-like TabControl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4130645/2012417).

Comment: I know about the TabControl class LOL. I am talking about the tabcontrol google chrome has on its border on top of the form...

Comment: @BernardBernyKozarić in which case you might want to check out the other link which points to a SO answer to a quite similar question